# Не получается авторизоваться в phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Немного софте: Ubuntu 16.04.1 TLS, PHP 7.0.8, MySQL-5.7, Apache2

Суть проблемы - не пускает в phpmyadmin. Дело в том, что при установки mysql я не устанавливал пароль для root. Во время установки phpmyadmin также никаких запросов по установки пароля не было (переустанавливал несколько раз уже). Но блин, для входа нужно авторизоваться, вход без пароля не разрешён. В замешательстве, что делать? Боюсь уже наковырял в настройках MySQL что-то не то.

Answer (score 1):

в режиме --skip-grant-tables проверьте/задайте пароль

в config.inc.php укажите нужные значения:
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = '...';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = '...';

подробности [тут](http://sqlinfo.ru/articles/info/16.html)